# How to edit [woocommerce_checkout] page to not show any address field?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site and WooCommerce activated. I have some downloadable products to sell, and I don't want to display any address field in [woocommerce_checkout] page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code to your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Or you could use a plugin to achieve the same result.